# Obtener una entidad desde en eventSubscriber

Tags: php, symfony2, symfony3, doctrine2

Estoy usando un eventSubscriber para cargar dinámicamente un campo (Paciente) en un formulario, del cual en su función `preSubmit` necesito obtener ademas del id el dni del paciente. El id lo puedo obtener directamente, pero el dni necesito traerme la entidad, y no sé cómo puedo hacerlo desde aquí.

Mi evento en cuestión es el siguiente:

```
class AddHistoriaClinicaFieldSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    private $propertyPathToHistoriaClinica;
    public function __construct($propertyPathToHistoriaClinica)
    {
        $this->propertyPathToHistoriaClinica = $propertyPathToHistoriaClinica;
    }
    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            FormEvents::POST_SET_DATA => 'preSetData',
            FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT    => 'preSubmit'
        );
    }
    private function addHistoriaClinicaForm($form, $paciente_id)
    {
        $formOptions = array(
            'class'         => 'BiobancoBundle:HistoriaClinica',
            'empty_value'   => '-- SELECCIONAR HISTORIA CLINICA --',
            'label'         => 'Historia Clínica',
            'attr'          => array(
                'class' => 'historia_clinica_selector',
            ),
            'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $repository) use ($paciente_id) {
                $qb = $repository->createQueryBuilder('h')
                    ->innerJoin('h.paciente', 'p')
                    ->where('p.id = :p')
                    ->setParameter('p', $paciente_id)
                ;
                return $qb;
            },
        );
        $form->add($this->propertyPathToHistoriaClinica, 'entity', $formOptions);
    }
    public function preSetData(FormEvent $event)
    {
        $data = $event->getData();
        $form = $event->getForm();
        if (null === $data) {
            return;
        }
        $accessor    = PropertyAccess::createPropertyAccessor();
        $h        = $accessor->getValue($data, $this->propertyPathToHistoriaClinica);
        $paciente_id = ($h) ? $h->getPaciente()->getNumeroIdentificacion() : null;
        $this->addHistoriaClinicaForm($form, $paciente_id);
    }
    public function preSubmit(FormEvent $event)
    {
        $data = $event->getData();
        $form = $event->getForm();
        $paciente_id = array_key_exists('paciente', $data) ? $data['paciente'] : null;
        //AQUÍ ES DONDE NECESITO OBTENER EL DNI, PARA PASARLO AL FORMULARIO
        //dump($data);die();
        $this->addHistoriaClinicaForm($form, $paciente_id);
    }
}
```

EDIT 1 DE preSubmit:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;

...

public function preSubmit(FormEvent $event, LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $data = $event->getData();
        $form = $event->getForm();
        $paciente_id = array_key_exists('paciente', $data) ? $data['paciente'] : null;
        dump($args->getEntityManager()->getRepository("BiobancoBundle:Paciente")->find($paciente_id));die();
        $this->addHistoriaClinicaForm($form, $paciente_id);
    }
```

El error, salta en la linea de la declaracion de la funcion, al inyectarle LifecycleEventArgs

Comment: Que versión específica de doctrine estás usando?

Comment: 2.5.5-DEV es la versión que estoy usando

Comment: Entonces no soy capaz de ver el error porque salta

Comment: De todos modos gracias, seguire investigando por ese camino ;)

Answer (score 1):

En la documentación oficial de symfony se encuentra esto para llamar a la entidad desde un `eventSubscriber`

```
public function getSubscribedEvents()
{
    return array(
        'postPersist',
        'postUpdate',
    );
}

public function postUpdate(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
{
    $this->index($args);
}

public function postPersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
{
    $this->index($args);
}

public function index(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
{
    $entity = $args->getEntity();

    // perhaps you only want to act on some "Product" entity
    if ($entity instanceof Product) {
        $entityManager = $args->getEntityManager();
        // ... do something with the Product
    }
}
```

Simplemente llamando a la entidad podrías invocarla y luego con cambiar los parámetro que indica la documentación debería funcionar

He encontrado documentación más explicita, a lo mejor añadiendo todos los métodos deja de saltar el error

Comment: Muchas gracias compañero,puedes pasarme el link ? Pero ahora al inyectarselo en el presubmit, me da el siguiente error: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 2 passed to BiobancoBundle\Form\EventListener\AddHistoriaClinicaFieldSubscriber::preSubmit() must be an instance of Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs, string given.

Comment: @IvanJavierBarrancoGavilan necesitas pasarle la instancia de Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs y según symfony le estás dando una cadena de texto, pon el código si puedes exactamente donde salta eel error

Comment: Procedo a actualizarlo, gracias

Comment: @IvanJavierBarrancoGavilan respuesta actualizada